# Make VP9 encoding faster with the best possible quality without picture freezing

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this code to combine 2 files together (overlay file over original file):

```
ffmpeg -r 60 \
        -i originalfile.webm -i overlayfile.mov \
        -filter_complex " \
            [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[base]; \
            [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0.5/TB, \
                 format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7[overlay]; \
             [base][overlay]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=0[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -threads 4 -quality realtime -speed 8 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -vsync 1 -shortest resultfile.webm
```

Encoding speed is not bad and quality output also, but after some time video picture could freeze for several seconds, then again it plays ok and then again could freeze.

How could I optimize this code to make fast speed with the highest possible quality as original file without picture freezing?

Thank you

Comment: Is the WebM a video capture, from WebRTC or similar?

Comment: No, it's output from music application, that only support webm output. Here is my desired result, but I see it has small freezes - https://youtu.be/Xu8YeCxlRVs?t=119

Comment: When does it freeze? I don't see it at t=119s.

Comment: I see it's overall not stable perfect as original webm file. Maybe some milliseconds of freezing, hard to show it. I was hoping I could change/remove some unneeded options from my code to make it playing perfect. When I play original webm, it has great video quality compared to converted one.

Comment: Remove the `-r 60` and change vsync to 2 and check.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've compared original and converted video side-by-side without "-r 60" and it has the same great quality. Maybe small freezing was due my low end computer. If it's not hard, could you tell me how can I crop "overlayfile.mov" to crop 10% of top and 10% of bottom, so I can remove unneeded logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid retiming of the webm and to crop 10% of the overlay from top and bottom, run

```
ffmpeg \
  -i originalfile.webm -i overlayfile.mov \
  -filter_complex " \
    [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[base]; \
    [1:v]crop=iw:0.80*ih,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0.5/TB, \
         format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7[overlay]; \
   [base][overlay]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=0[v]" \
 -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -threads 4 -quality realtime \
 -speed 8 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -vsync 2 -shortest resultfile.webm
```

The crop filter centers the crop window by default, so when cropping to 80%, the top and bottom 10% will get cut off.

Comment: Amazing, with your help I can publish great videos.